# rn-fetch-blob Vs axios for fetching data API

Tags: javascript, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-development

I need compare feature between "rn-fetch-blob" and "axios"
which one the best between "rn-fetch-blob" and "axios" for fetching data ?

Comment: for what it's worth, RNFetchBlob injects its own `fetch` implementation into the global namespace, which can cause issues when you just want the standard `fetch`. For that reason, I prefer to use axios

Comment: Please note that RNFetchBlob can't be used in Expo since it uses native code.